# How to apply implementation-depended method calls?

Tags: java, oop

I have a `delete(object)` method that should execute different code depending on which object is to be deleted.

```
class MyService {

   void delete(Object obj) {
     if (obj instanceof Foo) {
         //execute some foo deletion logic
     } 
     if (obj instanceof Bar) {
         //execute some bar deletion logic
     }
     //if... and so on
   }
}
```

From the design point of view, how can I avoid `instanceof` checks here?
I cannot introduce a `delete()` method in all of my implementations, as the objects should not know about how they should delete themselves.

What else is there?

Comment: I would make it an abstract method and let the children classes handle the deletion logic (similar with insert, update, retrieve, retrieveAll...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could still use a subclassing mechanism (you could even make it generic) by writing

```
class MyService<T> {
   void delete(T obj) {
     // Only the delete logic, but nothing specific for any type
   }
}
```

Then, for Foo, you'd make a subclass:

```
class MyFooService extends MyService<Foo> {
    void delete(Foo obj) {
        //execute some foo deletion logic
        // finally, invoke super class as it knows how to do the real delete action
        super.delete(obj);
    }
}
```

This way, your `Foo`-specific logic is in `MyFooService`, and your `Foo` logic is put into a seperate class. As an added bonus, this give you classes that can be well unit-tested.

Comment: This is very very neat! Think it will fit my needs best.

Answer (score 2):

Method overloading:

```
void delete(Foo f) {}
void delete(Bar b) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO its better to create an enum which represents DeleteType say

```
public enum DeleteType {

Foo, Bar  //..... }
```

and in `MyService` the delete method can take 2 arguments like,

```
void delete(DeleteType type, Object object) {
switch(type) {
case Foo:
 //Deletion of Foo objects....
 break;
case Bar:
//Deletion of Bar objects....
 break;
 ....
}
}
```

If you would like to have `delete` method signature intact, then the `type` can be stored within the `obj` itself (by making `obj`'s class adhere to a contract(`interface`) which will make it `return` its `type`)